# Angularjs expression is not working

Tags: angularjs

I tried to use the angular expression below in html 5 but it is not working.

index.html

```
* * < !DOCTYPE html >
< html >
< script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js" > < /script> < script src = "blockuijs.js" > < /script> < body >
< div ng - app = "icebreakerapp" >
< p > My first expression: {
    {
        5 + 5
    }
} </p> </div> < script >
var module = angular.module('icebreakerapp', ['blockUI']); < /script> < /body> < /html>**










blockuijs.js

(function(angular) {
var blkUI = angular.module('blockUI', []);
blkUI.config(["$provide", "$httpProvider", function($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$injector', function($delegate, $injector) {
        var blockUI, blockUIConfig;
        return function(exception, cause) {
            blockUIConfig = blockUIConfig || $injector.get('blockUIConfig');
            if (blockUIConfig.resetOnException) {
                blockUI = blockUI || $injector.get('blockUI');
                blockUI.instances.reset();
            }
            $delegate(exception, cause);
        };
    }]);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('blockUIHttpInterceptor');
}]);
blkUI.run(["$document", "blockUIConfig", "$templateCache", function($document, blockUIConfig, $templateCache) {
    if (blockUIConfig.autoInjectBodyBlock) {
        $document.find('body').attr('block-ui', 'main');
    }
    if (blockUIConfig.template) {
        blockUIConfig.templateUrl = '$$block-ui-template$$';
        $templateCache.put(blockUIConfig.templateUrl, blockUIConfig.template);
    }
}]);
blkUI.directive('blockUiContainer', ["blockUIConfig", "blockUiContainerLinkFn", function(blockUIConfig, blockUiContainerLinkFn) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: blockUIConfig.templateUrl,
        compile: function($element) {
            return blockUiContainerLinkFn;
        }
    };
}]).factory('blockUiContainerLinkFn', ["blockUI", "blockUIUtils", function(blockUI, blockUIUtils) {
    return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var srvInstance = $element.inheritedData('block-ui');
        if (!srvInstance) {
            throw new Error('No parent block-ui service instance located.');
        }
        $scope.state = srvInstance.state(); //
    };
}]);
blkUI.directive('blockUi', ["blockUiCompileFn", function(blockUiCompileFn) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: blockUiCompileFn
    };
}]).factory('blockUiCompileFn', ["blockUiPreLinkFn", function(blockUiPreLinkFn) {
    return function($element, $attrs) {
        $element.append('<div block-ui-container class="block-ui-container"></div>');
        return {
            pre: blockUiPreLinkFn
        };
    };
}]).factory('blockUiPreLinkFn', ["blockUI", "blockUIUtils", "blockUIConfig", function(blockUI, blockUIUtils, blockUIConfig) {
    return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        if (!$element.hasClass('block-ui')) {
            $element.addClass(blockUIConfig.cssClass);
        }
        $attrs.$observe('blockUiMessageClass', function(value) {
            $scope.$_blockUiMessageClass = value;
        });
        var instanceId = $attrs.blockUi || '_' + $scope.$id;
        var srvInstance = blockUI.instances.get(instanceId);
        if (instanceId === 'main') {
            var fn = $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function($event) {
                fn();
                $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
                    if (srvInstance.state().blockCount > 0) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            var parentInstance = $element.inheritedData('block-ui');
            if (parentInstance) {
                srvInstance._parent = parentInstance;
            }
        }
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            srvInstance.release();
        });
        srvInstance.addRef();
        $scope.$_blockUiState = srvInstance.state();
        $scope.$watch('$_blockUiState.blocking', function(value) {
            $element.attr('aria-busy', !!value);
            $element.toggleClass('block-ui-visible', !!value);
        });
        $scope.$watch('$_blockUiState.blockCount > 0', function(value) {
            $element.toggleClass('block-ui-active', !!value);
        });
        var pattern = $attrs.blockUiPattern;
        if (pattern) {
            var regExp = blockUIUtils.buildRegExp(pattern);
            srvInstance.pattern(regExp);
        }
        $element.data('block-ui', srvInstance);
    };
}]);
blkUI.constant('blockUIConfig', {
    templateUrl: 'angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.ng.html',
    delay: 250,
    message: "Loading ...",
    autoBlock: true,
    resetOnException: true,
    requestFilter: angular.noop,
    autoInjectBodyBlock: true,
    cssClass: 'block-ui block-ui-anim-fade'
});
blkUI.factory('blockUIHttpInterceptor', ["$q", "$injector", "blockUIConfig", function($q, $injector, blockUIConfig) {
    var blockUI;

    function injectBlockUI() {
        blockUI = blockUI || $injector.get('blockUI');
    }

    function stopBlockUI(config) {
        if (blockUIConfig.autoBlock && !config.$_noBlock && config.$_blocks) {
            injectBlockUI();
            config.$_blocks.stop();
        }
    }

    function error(rejection) {
        stopBlockUI(rejection.config);
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            if (blockUIConfig.autoBlock) {
                if (blockUIConfig.requestFilter(config) === false) {
                    config.$_noBlock = true;
                } else {
                    injectBlockUI();
                    config.$_blocks = blockUI.instances.locate(config);
                    config.$_blocks.start();
                }
            }
            return config;
        },
        requestError: error,
        response: function(response) {
            stopBlockUI(response.config);
            return response;
        },
        responseError: error
    };
}]);
blkUI.factory('blockUI', ["blockUIConfig", "$timeout", "blockUIUtils", "$document", function(blockUIConfig, $timeout, blockUIUtils, $document) {
    var $body = $document.find('body');

    function BlockUI(id) {
        var self = this;
        var state = {
                id: id,
                blockCount: 0,
                message: blockUIConfig.message,
                blocking: false
            },
            startPromise, doneCallbacks = [];
        this._refs = 0;
        this.start = function(message) {
            if (state.blockCount > 0) {
                message = message || state.message || blockUIConfig.message;
            } else {
                message = message || blockUIConfig.message;
            }
            state.message = message;
            state.blockCount++;
            var $ae = angular.element($document[0].activeElement);
            if ($ae.length && blockUIUtils.isElementInBlockScope($ae, self)) { //
                self._restoreFocus = $ae[0];
                $timeout(function() {
                    if (self._restoreFocus) {
                        self._restoreFocus.blur();
                    }
                });
            }
            if (!startPromise) {
                startPromise = $timeout(function() {
                    startPromise = null;
                    state.blocking = true;
                }, blockUIConfig.delay);
            }
        };
        this._cancelStartTimeout = function() {
            if (startPromise) {
                $timeout.cancel(startPromise);
                startPromise = null;
            }
        };
        this.stop = function() {
            state.blockCount = Math.max(0, --state.blockCount);
            if (state.blockCount === 0) {
                self.reset(true);
            }
        };
        this.message = function(value) {
            state.message = value;
        };
        this.pattern = function(regexp) {
            if (regexp !== undefined) {
                self._pattern = regexp;
            }
            return self._pattern;
        };
        this.reset = function(executeCallbacks) {
            self._cancelStartTimeout();
            state.blockCount = 0;
            state.blocking = false;
            if (self._restoreFocus && (!$document[0].activeElement || $document[0].activeElement === $body[0])) {
                self._restoreFocus.focus();
                self._restoreFocus = null;
            }
            try {
                if (executeCallbacks) {
                    angular.forEach(doneCallbacks, function(cb) {
                        cb();
                    });
                }
            } finally {
                doneCallbacks.length = 0;
            }
        };
        this.done = function(fn) {
            doneCallbacks.push(fn);
        };
        this.state = function() {
            return state;
        };
        this.addRef = function() {
            self._refs += 1;
        };
        this.release = function() {
            if (--self._refs <= 0) {
                mainBlock.instances._destroy(self);
            }
        };
    }
    var instances = [];
    instances.get = function(id) {
        var instance = instances[id];
        if (!instance) {
            instance = instances[id] = new BlockUI(id);
            instances.push(instance);
        }
        return instance;
    };
    instances._destroy = function(idOrInstance) {
        if (angular.isString(idOrInstance)) {
            idOrInstance = instances[idOrInstance];
        }
        if (idOrInstance) {
            idOrInstance.reset();
            delete instances[idOrInstance.state().id];
            var i = instances.length;
            while (--i) {
                if (instances[i] === idOrInstance) {
                    instances.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    instances.locate = function(request) {
        var result = [];
        blockUIUtils.forEachFnHook(result, 'start');
        blockUIUtils.forEachFnHook(result, 'stop');
        var i = instances.length;
        while (i--) {
            var instance = instances[i];
            var pattern = instance._pattern;
            if (pattern && pattern.test(request.url)) {
                result.push(instance);
            }
        }
        if (result.length === 0) {
            result.push(mainBlock);
        }
        return result;
    };
    blockUIUtils.forEachFnHook(instances, 'reset');
    var mainBlock = instances.get('main');
    mainBlock.addRef();
    mainBlock.instances = instances;
    return mainBlock;
}]);
blkUI.factory('blockUIUtils', function() {
    var $ = angular.element;
    var utils = {
        buildRegExp: function(pattern) {
            var match = pattern.match(/^\/(.*)\/([gim]*)$/),
                regExp;
            if (match) {
                regExp = new RegExp(match[1], match[2]);
            } else {
                throw Error('Incorrect regular expression format: ' + pattern);
            }
            return regExp;
        },
        forEachFn: function(arr, fnName, args) {
            var i = arr.length;
            while (i--) {
                var t = arr[i];
                t[fnName].apply(t, args);
            }
        },
        forEachFnHook: function(arr, fnName) {
            arr[fnName] = function() {
                utils.forEachFn(this, fnName, arguments);
            }
        },
        isElementInBlockScope: function($element, blockScope) {
            var c = $element.inheritedData('block-ui');
            while (c) {
                if (c === blockScope) {
                    return true;
                }
                c = c._parent;
            }
            return false;
        },
        findElement: function($element, predicateFn, traverse) {
            var ret = null;
            if (predicateFn($element)) {
                ret = $element;
            } else {
                var $elements;
                if (traverse) {
                    $elements = $element.parent();
                } else {
                    $elements = $element.children();
                }
                var i = $elements.length;
                while (!ret && i--) {
                    ret = utils.findElement($($elements[i]), predicateFn, traverse);
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    };
    return utils;
});


angular.module('blockUI').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.ng.html', '<div class=\"block-ui-overlay\"></div><div class=\"block-ui-message-container\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\"><div class=\"block-ui-message loading_spinnerlatest\" ng-class=\"$_blockUiMessageClass\">{{ state.message }}</div></div>');
}]);
```

})(angular); //

It is giving the output as `"My first expression:{{ 5+5}}"`.But expectation is `"My first expression:10"`

Note: If I remove dependency modules in (angular.module) it is working.But I need those dependency modules
for further development

Comment: You must include source for all your dependencies too or else Angular is going to throw an error. Check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing any error in console? Maybe some of your module dependencies are not resolved.
Check this snippet:

```html
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="icebreakerapp">
<p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
</div>
<script>
var module = angular.module('icebreakerapp', []);
</script>
```

Comment: I concur you are not including any of the JS srcs for angular.ui which I know will cause an error, you are not including the bootstrap css as well.  Your other dependencies need to be resolved as well.  I would suggest adding them back in one at a time, doing a google search for what you need to include to resolve them.

Comment: thanks praveen.. i   found out the issue is with the  blockuijs. But i am not able to resolve it.. please find the details below

Comment: james i have removed all other dependencies and included only blockuijs.js. Please find the details above

Comment: In the plunkr you added, you have not included ui bootstrap module, I removed that dependency and it worked fine.